# Windows Developer License Registration is stuck

Tags: c#

I wanted to move on from Visual Basic to C#, so the other day I tried to create an application. It told me I need to get a developer license (at that time I was on holiday, so I couldn't be bothered). When I got home, I did the same to press I agree and now it is stuck on Contacting License Server for over 1 hour. I have  tried different tutorials but nothing seems to help to get this on to the next step.

Any ideas?

Comment: exactly what development product are you using? check help -> about.

Comment: If you clicked on agree and the license server doesn't respond, It isn't clear what you think someone here can do.

Comment: @FrankThomas Microsoft Visual Basic 2013 Community

Comment: @fixer1234 It worked once. Then, it didn't work again. As I put in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer now:

I just had to restart once, try to get a Developer License, then restart again and then it worked!